# subsonic with ASP.net MVC2 strongly typed views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I have an MVC project setup, and I've brought the subsonic Active Record templates into my project, and they generated successfully and I can use the subsonic classes to access my database.  However, how do I create a strongly typed view using the subsonic generated classes?  When I select "add View" and I check the checkbox to create a strongly-typed view, none of the generated classes from subsonic for my data are available.  How do I do this?

Comment: Did you built your project before you start making the view?

Comment: That was it!  I didn't realize I had to build my project before those classes would show up in the list.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to compile your project first.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it manually and see if you get any errors. Crack open your view and change:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"
```

to

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Your.Strongly.Typed.ClassName>"
```

You can also add the namespace in the web.config under pages->namespaces

```
<add namespace="Your.Strongly.Typed" />
```

if you want to shorten the change to:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ClassName>"
```